# Can you speed up JOINs which return large number of rows? Can you suggest a better schema for a video-sharing site?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

So I am currently working on a private project and some of the data is very specific, but I will use a video-sharing site as an analogy, since the requirements would be equivalent. The main entities the site would have would be:

- Videos(id, userID, name, creationDate, viewCount, duration)
- Playlists(id, userID, name, creationDate, viewCount, numOfVideos)
- Users(id, name, creationDate, viewCount, isVerified)

With this format, I'd also need some kind of `Playlist_Video(playlist_id, video_id)` relation too of course.

So, this is just a simplified version, but as you can see, the fields `name` and `creationDate` are common to all 3 entities.

Since I want the user to be able to use **one search form** and have `Videos`, `Playlists` and `Users` returned by the query/queries, to avoid data redundancy & to make LIMIT return a representative set of all 3 types, I thought I would see what performance was like if I created another table, as though it was inheritence in OOP - let's call it `Item(id, name, creationDate, viewCount)`, then those other tables would just have the fields that were unique to themselves - e.g. Video would now simply be `Video(id, duration)`

From a simplicity point of view, this seemed to be like it could work, however I run into problems when I want to do queries like

"SELECT all the playlists and videos with more than 1 million views uploaded by verified users, ordered by most recent"

Afterall, my query ended up being something like:

```
Select *
FROM item i
INNER JOIN video v ON v.id = i.id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = v.id
WHERE v.viewCount > 1 AND isVerfiied = true ORDER BY v.creationDate DESC LIMIT 100
```

And to be honest, I didn't even get onto joining it with playlists...possibly I could do it within the same select, or possibly I'd need a UNION or something. All I know is that when this query took over 5 minutes, I didn't even attempt with playlists too. Basically the table sizes as as follows:

- Videos = 10,000,000
- Users & playlists = 1,000,000 each

The ids are obviously indexed being primary keys, just as there are indexes on the name, creationDate, viewCount, duration and numOfVideos too.

As you can see in this query, when the WHERE clause returns lots of results (i.e. when viewCount is low), then the query takes a long time - however, if the WHERE clause is restrictive (say, viewCount > 1000000), then the query will return in like 0.2s or less. Likewise, if I join 2 of the tables and have the WHERE and LIMIT 100 clause, it will return it milliseconds, because it is just fetching those 100 rows, then joining them...but when

Here are the results of running `EXPLAIN`:

[image: Here are the results of running EXPLAIN]

So the main questions I have are:

1. If you have the WHERE conditions in different tables and the items can only be ordered in a certain way - say the join order is table A->B->C (and you can't join A & C directly, without using B) and you want to have WHERE conditions from values in tables A & C, is there any way to improve performance - i.e. otherwise you have to JOIN all valid rows in A, with all rows in C before you can apply the LIMIT, since if you LIMIT the result from A->B, then if the WHERE condition on C is too harsh, then you will get too few or often even zero rows returned - the only way I can think of would be putting something like `isVerified` in my example in the items class, then you wouldn't need to JOIN with the user...but then when a user becomes verified, potentially 100s or 1000s of rows in the `Item` table would have to have their isVerified field `UPDATE...SET` to `true`...if this field isn't indexed, I guess it would be ok possibly...but when I have tried to mass-update indexed fields before, other queries seem to often get locked out...
2. Is creating an OOP kind of style `Item` table a bad idea - would it be better just to only have the 3 `Videos`, `Playlists` and `Users` tables, then, when the user searches for something, submit a seperate `SELECT` query to each of the 3 tables? With this approach, would it be possible to easily & efficiently get the correct number of each type rows from each - if you wanted to get 20 results, that might be 15 videos, 3 playlists and 2 users, for example. So the `LIMIT 20` should apply across all rows, as if they were in one table

Anyway, hopefully I have explained myself well enough and I'd appreciate if anyone has some advice or pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Best to tag only a single RDBMS, because at this level the techniques could be quite different. That said you question is way too board for this site.

Comment: Fair enough. I mean, I tagged multiple DBMS's since I have tried with multiple ones, after MySQL was initially showing some strange behaviour (like selecting indexes on a simple WHERE...ORDER BY...LIMIT) that would take 10000x longer than if I manually-forced the index. I am open to using any DBMS, providing the performance is good. What I have found that is that despite the 3 or 4 different table structures etc I've tried, even if 9 of the queries are fast, there will always be at least 1 type of query that is unusable - like 20, 60, sometimes even 300 seconds...

Comment: There are also too many different questions in there. For example, the query you show has two potentially selective conditions, both on the same table. Then you wander off into queries where the selective conditions are on different tables. It is hard to give a general satisfactory answer to all that. You should focus the question on one aspect.